# Stata: Esttab Long Labels

Tags: stata

I am using estpost and esttab commands to create frequency distribution tables. However, the labels of my categorical variables are too long and Stata crops the variable labels.

```
sysuse auto, clear

label define longlabel 0 "domestic car domestic car domestic car domestic car domestic car" ///
1 "foreign car foreign car foreign car foreign car foreign car" 

label values foreign longlabel

estpost tabulate foreign 
esttab ., cells("b") eqlabels(`e(eqlabels)') varlabels(`e(labels)') label
```

```
---------------------------------
                              (1)
                         Car type
                                b
---------------------------------
domestic car domes~t           52
foreign car foreig~            22
Total                          74
---------------------------------
Observations                   74
---------------------------------
```

Is there a way to force Stata to save the full labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option `noabbrev` to prevent truncation, or `varwidth(#)` to set the width of the first column.